# populate dates for current week in 7 cells

Tags: excel

looking for a way populate seven cells with the current weeks dates. Like MONDAY - SUNDAY and the dates if the current week in the cells below each:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--+
| SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY |  |
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--+
| 10/15  | 10/16  | 10/17   | 10/18     | 10/19    | 10/20  | 10/21    |  |
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--+
```

Comment: Do you always want to start with Sunday or the previous Sunday ??

Comment: monday would be fine (current week for all seven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,TODAY(),TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-2))
```

Im **B1** enter:

```
=A1+1
```

and copy across:

[image]

So if today is Monday, **A1** will be today's date.  If today is not Monday, then **A1** will be the date of the previous Monday *(start of the week)*.

Comment: So if I want the week to start with Sunday I would put function in B1 and A1 would still be B1+1

Comment: @BarclayVision Yes you would change the twos in cell **A1** and leave the other cells alone.

Comment: @BarclayVision  on my computer **=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=1,TODAY(),TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1))** displays  Sunday, October 15, 2017

Comment: got it, sorry.. so Monday cell is A1+1 and Tuesday cell is A!+2, act...

Comment: @BarclayVision  Sorry...I should have mentioned that **both** twos should be changed.

Comment: You did, thanks it's working as desired... I have another question about how to keep a YTD total on weekly time card like this - but i'll ask in new question.

Comment: To get Monday date of current week simpler to use `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)`